# Find index of first greater than or equal values of a vector in another one

Tags: matlab, vector

I have two sorted vectors `x` and `y`.  For each `y(i)`, I want to find the first index `j` such that `y(i) >= x(j)`.

Example:

```
x = [1 3 5 7 9 11 13 15]
y = [3 4 5 9 10 11]
result = [2 2 3 5 5 6]
```

What is the most efficient way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) and [`min`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/min.html) comes to mind:

```
[~,result] = min(bsxfun(@gt, y(:), x(:).'), [], 2)
```

You can take advantage of broadcasting where you can create two 2D matrices with `y` being duplicated over the columns and `x` being duplicated over the rows. I take the **opposite** problem where for each value of `y`, we find the first location that is the **smallest**. The result would thus give you the solution for each value in `y`.  Mind you, I could have approached this using `max` and reversed the comparison operation, but I like this way better.

## Example Run

```
>> x = [1 3 5 7 9 11 13 15]

x =

     1     3     5     7     9    11    13    15

>> y = [3 4 5 9 10 11]

y =

     3     4     5     9    10    11

>>  [~,result] = min(bsxfun(@gt, y(:), x(:).'), [], 2)

result =

     2
     3
     3
     5
     6
     6
```

## Minor Note

I have a feeling you're going to use this for linear interpolation :)

Comment: Yes, your're right. Thanks.

Comment: No problem. I've marked an appropriate duplicate for you since I now know what your end goal is. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Because the vector x is partially ordered (and therefore monotonic), one does need to transverse the whole x for every entry in y. The following code should work in MATLAB:

```
lastOccurrence=1
for i = 1:length(y)
  for j = lastOccurrence:length(x)
    if y(i)<x(j)
      lastOccurence=j-1
      result(i) = j-1
      break
    end
  end
end
```